# View Not Returning Multiple Lists in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i am new to web from desktop.

i have two models.

first

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Stock { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

and second is

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

and a ViewModel for passing it to my view

```
public class ProductsVM
{
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> categories { get; set; }

}
```

and my controller action method looks like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Products()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "...Products...";

        ProductsVM productsVm = new ProductsVM();
        productsVm.items = db.Items.ToList();
        productsVm.categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        return View(productsVm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Products(ProductsVM model)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "...Categories...";



        return View(model);
    }
```

i have used it in my view like this

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @foreach (var it in Model.categories.ToList())
                {
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => it.isSelected, new { Name =         "ChkCategory", id = "ChkCategory"+it.Id, @class = "Categories" }) @it.Name
                        @Html.HiddenFor(i => it.Name)

                    </div>
                }
            </div>

            @*Loading Items...*@
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.items.Count() / 3; i++)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                   @foreach (var item in Model.items.Skip(i *         3).Take(3))
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="@item.Description" class="thumbnail" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }


    @section scripts
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/Products.js"></script>
    }
```

i have tried all the ways to get my model back when i post the from to controller

i am posting the from on checkbox click event using ajax from my products.js file.

but in my controller action method it always show the ViewModel as null.

what should i do? am i doing something wrong.

Products.js

```
    $(function () {
        console.log('Inside js......');
        $('.Categories').click(function (e) {
            console.log(this.id, $("#" + this.id).is(":checked"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Products",
                success: function () {
                    console.log("ajax successfull....");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("ajax error....");
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Show your Products.js

Comment: yup if you show your products.js it will helpful for us to debug.thanks

Comment: In addition to the dupe (you cannot use a `foreach` loop, do not attempt to change the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `ProductsVM`:

```
public class ProductsVM
{
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> categories { get; set; }
}
```

This is your action method to which you are posting:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Products(ProductsVM model)
```

When you submit your form, it will take the values from your form's controls and using the names of the controls, it will post them to the `Products` action. In your view (form), you have a checkbox with the name `chkCategory` and a hidden input with the name `Name`. When you post your form, it will send `chkCategory` and its value, and the hidden item with the name `Name`. When it arrives on the server side, the MVC will look for an action method named `Products` in your controller. Then the default binder will try to look for `chkCategory` and `Name` properties to see if the action accepts them. It will not find it. Then it will try to see if it can create a `ProductsVM` and it cannot because `ProductsVM` has 2 properties: `items` and `categories` and they do not match what you are posting so it will just choose that action and pass it null.

You have many issues in your code and it is not playing nicely with the whole MVC framework. I suggest you read [Understanding MVC Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and try some simple examples to get a hang of it and then try what you are doing.

Comment: sir can u please prove some other link to know more about how MVC Model Binder works, the link you have provided is broken. And in little sense i understand your answer. Thank you sir.

Comment: @jardeepkarena I changed the link so it should work now. Just Google [how DefaultModelBinder works](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ms-android-rogers-ca&ei=EjUqW4zFOKusjwTa7Y3oBQ&q=asp+mvc+how+default+model+binder+works&oq=asp+mvc+how+default+model+binder+works&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...14918.26285..27571...0....214.1175.4j5j1......0....1.........0i71j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i21j33i160.NrHTggHIFuI%3D). Hope that helps.